# Find and replace few words in text file with using bash

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, search, replace

I have a script to, where in one variable words, that i have in file, in other variable, i have words, that i want use instead words from first variable. I need to find `i am scatman` and replace these words to `you are dukenukem`. For example, my text file, `wwe.txt`:

```
i

      am



dsadsa
sda
daaaa
ds
dsds
dsa
d


scatman
```

For example, i wrote script, that makes grep, and it works:

```
words="i am scatman"
echo "$words"

for i in $words; do
if grep -q "$i" wwe.txt; then
        echo "these words are exists"
        grep "$i" wwe.txt
else
        echo "these words are not exists"
        exit 1
fi
done
```

It works. But if i want, to replace these words, how i can do this ? i wrote this:

```
words="i am scatman"
words2="you are dukenukem"

for i in $words; do
for y in $words2; do
if grep -q "$i" wwe.txt; then
        echo "these words are exists"
        grep "$i" wwe.txt
        sed -i 's/'"$i"'/'"$y"'/g' wwe.txt
else
        echo "these words are not exists"
        exit 1
fi
done
done
```

But it does not work, where i have error ? Help please.

Comment: what if there would be multiple `i` or `am` substrings, what should happen?

Comment: it will in the next level of script. now, i think it simple example

Comment: `sed 's/i/you/; s/am/are/; s/scatman/dukenumen/' file.txt` providing that those strings are unique

Comment: yes, but i how to do it in a loop. because in a future, i will replace more than 3 words

Comment: `sed "s/$word1/$word2/"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works. Please try it out.

```
#!/bin/bash

line1="i am scatman"

line2="you are dukenukem"
words2=($line2)

count=0
for word in $line1; do
    sed -i -e "s/$word/${words2[$count]}/g" wwe.txt
    count=$((count + 1))
done
```